# Repeated "Not found: Job" error message on tab opening

Tags: google-bigquery, jobs

I'm getting the following error message every time I open any new tab in BigQuery, or when I move between tabs. It's been happening now for a couple of months and it is driving me nuts!

"Not found: Job xxx-xx-xxxxx:EU.bquxjob_4ee13939_17b074e777e" (I've anonymised the dataset)

No one else at my organisation is having this, which makes me think its a local cache/setting issue.

I've tried looking for "17b074e777e" in my personal history but can't see any reference to it.

Has anyone seen this before? Thanks

Comment: I am also getting the same since few days. A specific job id keeps poping up as "Not found: Job xxxxxxxx:EU.bquxjob_65bf2dfa_18224c5491a" whenever i execute any query in the BQ console. This job not found when i tried searching with bq show ... command from BQ CLI.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. While searching, i found this [API call to bigquery.jobs.getQueryResults failed with error: Not found: Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63842641/api-call-to-bigquery-jobs-getqueryresults-failed-with-error-not-found-job?rq=4), and turns out we need to set location manually on bigquery console query settings

1. open empty bigquery query console
2. go to more (with settings icon on it)
3. go to Query settings
4. open Advanced options
5. uncheck Automatic location selection
6. set your region manually, then save

the error should be vanished

reference

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/locations#specify_locations